# My code don't find the datagridview datasource after running another form at the same time

Tags: c#, forms, datagridview, parameters, datasource

I'm setting a IT project for the school and i got a problem with the datagridview in c# Winform.

I made a first form with a datagridview connected to my db and i want to make a button who can delete a row from the datagridview if needed.

To make sure the client doesn't make a mistake, i create another form where it ask "do you want to delete this row ? (yes/no)", that's a basic form (label + button).

But when i want to close this form, i go to a function in my first datagrid who will initialize this grid from the start of the program and in this code I use Datagridview.DataSource to make a loop.

The problem is marked here, and when I print my DataSource, it print me nothing like there is no DataSource...

Does anyone the reason or how to keep the DataSource from the previous form when you pop's up a new one ?

My code for the initial grid

```
public void InitDatagrid()
        {
            //Initialize the tools
            CancelMod.Visible = false;
            ApplyMod.Visible = false;
            Modifie.Visible = true;
            Prevbtn.Visible = true;
            ClientCommand.Enabled = true;
            Client_Pieces.Enabled = true;
            Prices.Enabled = true;
            PieceCommand.Enabled = true;
            Pieces.Enabled = true;
            textBox1.Enabled = true;
            RowAdd.Visible = false;
            RowDelete.Visible = false;
            textboxDel.Visible = false;
            labelDel.Visible = false;
            dataGridView1.EditMode = 
            DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgrammatically;
            textBox1.Text = "";
            this.pieceTableAdapter.Fill(this.mykitboxDataSet5.piece);
            //Put the color of the columns as white (initial color)
            for (var i = 0; i < ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                dataGridView1.Columns[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
            }

            int count = ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).Columns.Count;
            //Put the changed cells color as white (initial color) 
            if (count == 8)
            {
                dataGridView2.EditMode = 
                DataGridViewEditMode.EditProgrammatically;
                DeleteCommand.Visible = false;
                textBoxDel2.Visible = false;
                labelDel2.Visible = false;
                for (int i = 0; i < Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows.Count.ToString()); i++)
                {
                    //Column = payment_status and command_status
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].Style.BackColor = Color.White;
                    dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[7].Style.BackColor = Color.White;
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is my code for the pop up

```
        public PopUpDel(string codedb, string text, DataGridView ds)
        {
            this.codedb = codedb;
            InitializeComponent();
            code.Text = codedb;
            label1.Text = text;
            Console.WriteLine(ds);
        }

        private void yes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SKGridPage sk = new SKGridPage();

            sk.SqlConnection();
            MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = string.Format("DELETE FROM piece WHERE code = '{0}'", this.codedb);
            Console.WriteLine(command.CommandText);
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (Exception x)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(x.Message);
            }
            conn.Close();

            this.Close();
            sk.InitDatagrid();
        }

        private void no_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you realize that calling InitializeComponent will reinitialize everything in your form? Overwriting everything you have done to your controls from the first call to InitializeComponent. Why are you calling again InitializeComponent?

Comment: Rather than an entire form to ask a tedious *Are You Sure* you can also use a `MessageBox` which might simplify things.

Comment: Hell Yeah MessageBox are nice for this operation, thanks !

Comment: But i want also put a pop up when i want to add a line in my db and it need a lot of textbox. So i think for this, MessageBox is not the solution and i make a whole form of textbox. And on this form i have the same problem...

Comment: I'm Calling InitializeComponent when the 'job' is done and i want that the client restart the software from the start